# Nginx config: log_not_found not working

Tags: nginx

I can't figure out why **log_not_found off** is not working with try_files. The errors "failed (2: No such file or directory)" always saved in error_log

Without try_files, **log_not_found off** work perfectly

My config:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf)$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    log_not_found off;
}

location ~* \.(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(.*) .....;
}
```

Comment: There must be no space between = and 404

Comment: Still not clear why do you want try_files here

Comment: How about switching the order of `try_files` and `log_not_found`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen order doesn't matter

Comment: Effectively, the space between = and 404 cause the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of Alexey Ten (in the comments), and for the public googler's benefit:

`"There must be no space between = and 404`